# per-row boolean operations in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, boolean, any

I have a Pandas Dataframe (see below). I'm trying to find a fast (and concise!) way to generate a column **d** containing a boolean, that is true, if any of **a**, **b** or **c** in the corresponding row are True. *without using a for loop*. I just couldn't get it to work using vectorization.
Thanks in advance!

#### my Dataframe:

| a | b | c |
| --- | --- | --- |
| True | False | True |
| False | True | False |
| False | False | False |

#### what I've tried:

I tried using any(), but that evaluates to True, if any value in *the entire frame* equals True.

I also managed to achieve the correct result using a for loop and apply any() on every single row, but after a certain number of rows that's just too slow.

> *edit: fixed table formatting*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.any`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.any.html):

```
df['d'] = df.any(axis=1)
```

If need specify columns for test:

```
df['d'] = df[['a','b','c']].any(axis=1)
```

Comment: Well, now I feel stupid, It didn't work when I tried because I didn't specify the axis... thank you so much. :)

Comment: @till_n If your problem is solved, you should accept the answer rather than just saying thank you. This will help others who see this question.

Comment: I know, he was so fast it didn't let me accept the answer yet. ;)